# Trash box is getting full quickly with dyld_shared_cache_arm64 file

Tags: xcode, android-studio, macos-mojave, docker-desktop, adobe-xd

My mac got a trash box always full soon. Even if I clean trash box, it cause over and over again.
Does anyone know what is `dyld_shared_cache_arm64` files?

[image]

Please let me know how handle it.

Comment: Is that Xcode 11.5? Just started happening to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason.
However I figured out.

Whenever I have my iPhone8 connect into Mac with USB Cabel.
Every one minutes, 1.62Gb back up file were made.

I stoped to connect iPhone8 and Mac to get charge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly also happening to me, in my case, i was uninstalling and then installing again Xcode. After some time browsing i found this article that helped me, simply disconnect your phone, open Xcode, go to Window > Devices and Simulators
then
Connect your phone, after it appeared on Devices pane, unpair it, and then disconnect again, reconnect you phone, and do the pairing mechanism and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

dyld_shared_cache means dynamic library shared cache.
Macos may share sth with IOS while connects to your IOS device.